# Handle Navigation Controller for Log Out

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

This is the Navigation Stack of my App.
New User

- Splash -> LoginVIewController -> TabBarController (With Navigation
  Controller on Each Tab) -> Tab(3) ProfileViewController -> User
  Clicks on Logout

Existing User (Already Logged in user)

- Splash -> TabBarController (With Navigation    Controller on Each
  Tab) -> Tab(3) ProfileViewController -> User    Clicks on Logout

How should I create a segue so that there is no memory leak? When the user clicks on the LogOut Button. It should create a new instance of LoginViewController and all the allocated memory of TabbarController should be removed.

Comment: LoginVIewController have a navigtionController ?

Comment: No, right it doesn't have it. Should I add it? Is it a bad practice to have multiple navigation controllers for every view controller? Because every tab of the Tabbar controller does have a navigation controller attached to it for further screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new object of LoginVIewController and set it as a rootViewController.

```
   let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
   let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
   UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc
   UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: A follow-up question
Is it a good practice to change rootViewController after SplashViewController has completed its animation? So, that I can put my custom Splash Screen out of memory because I no longer needs it anyway.

Comment: Yes you can, these are some memory optimisation approach.